# Drupal 7 OpenLayers Map Relationship

Tags: drupal, view, openlayers

I have an OpenLayers Map that gives me a Table and a Map display of locations based on a Great-Circle. I have an Entity Reference from Locations to my Products content type. I want to display Products that are available at locations near me.

My problem is: I want to display two types of contact - Products and Locations. I want to display Products in a table and Locations in a map. How can I setup the table to pull the contextual arguments for the products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I didn't need to separate the data...just group by it and hide everything I don't want. I created the Relationship in Views and then added the Fields, then hid all the Location data I didn't want to see.